# Rails Admin not listing records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, action, rails-admin

So I've made a custom action for my mongoid model which is used for uploading an XSL document to MongoDB.
This action works fine, I can see that the XSL document and model record is being saved in the database, and it returns me back to my list where I can view the name of the stylesheet etc.

When I try access this list from outside the action (i.e. browsing to /admin/xsl_sheet) I get "Nothing to display". I don't understand why this would be the case.

Model:

```
require 'mongoid/grid_fs'

class XslSheet
  include Mongoid::Document

  scope :applicationId, -> {where(assetable_id: User.current_user.current_scope['Application']) unless User.current_user.nil? or User.current_user.current_scope.nil?}

  belongs_to :application
  validates_uniqueness_of [:data_file_name, :stylesheet_id], :scope => :assetable_id

  field :data_file_name, type: String
  field :assetable_id, type: Integer
  field :stylesheet_id, type: BSON::ObjectId
end
```

rails_admin.rb:

```
# XslSheet
c.model XslSheet do
  label Proc.new {"Xsl Sheet"}
  navigation_label Proc.new {I18n.t('navigation.actions')}
  weight 303
  navigation_icon 'fa fa-envelope-o'
  list do
    binding.pry
    scopes [:applicationId]
    field :data_file_name
    field :assetable_id
    field :stylesheet_id
  end
end
```

It may be interesting to note that when I access the list through browsing to it, the binding.pry in rails_admin.rb is triggered.
When I create a new `XslSheet` and get redirected, it does not catch in the binding.

Answer (score 0):

I was saving my model to the wrong database.

I switched to another DB to save the stylesheet, forgot to switch back to default for saving the record.